# Sending message to explorer.exe main window with a hook causes crash?

Tags: c++, winapi, hook, hwnd

I am trying to set a `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook on a window using the `HWND` I got from `WindowFromPoint` and send a message `WM_USER+x` after. But depending on the `HWND` I use it crashes the window.

Let me explain the scenario:

When getting an `HWND` through the `WindowFromPoint` function you sometimes get one of the children's instead of the main window.

Pretty good visualized with the Finder tool inside spy++

[image: HWND's]

So I simply get the window

```
wcout << "INFO: Waiting 1 second before first hwnd...\n";
this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000));
HWND targetHwnd = getHwndFromMousePos(); //Gets hwnd from mouse pos with WindowFromPoint
outHwndData(targetHwnd);
DWORD targetPID;
DWORD targetTID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(targetHwnd, &targetPID);
```

then set the hook by using the exported function of the dll.

```
hook = setHook(targetTID); //hook is the global HHOOK and setHook is a exported function in a dll
if (hook == NULL) {
    cout << "ERROR: Could not set hook\n";
    return 1;
}
```

The function inside the dll looks like so

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) HHOOK __stdcall setHook(DWORD targetTid) {
    return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, wmProcCallback, hInst, targetTid);
}
```

When `targetHwnd` is a children `HWND`, I hook, send message -> works fine

But when `targetHwnd` is the upper `HWND` (green marked one), I hook it, send a message -> it crashes.

[image]

So at the end `SetWindowsHookEx` works, but I am unable to send any messages to that found window if it is the upper `HWND` (green marked one). Why is that so?

This full demo code will wait 1 second before picking up the `HWND`. By hovering the mouse over the title bar on an explorer.exe window you can get the `HWND` that causes the crash.

Application code:

```
//This is the app
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

typedef HHOOK(WINAPI* DLLFUNC_SETHOOK) (DWORD);

HINSTANCE dllInstance;
DLLFUNC_SETHOOK setHook;

HHOOK hook;

HWND getHwndFromMousePos() {
    POINT cursorPos;
    if (GetCursorPos(&cursorPos) == FALSE) {
        cout << "ERROR: Could not get Cursor position...\n";
        return NULL;
    }
    HWND wnd = WindowFromPoint(cursorPos);
    if (wnd == NULL) {
        cout << "ERROR: No window found on this point\n";
        return NULL;
    }
    return wnd;
}


int main() {

    wcout << "INFO: Waiting 1 second before first hwnd...\n";
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    HWND targetHwnd = getHwndFromMousePos();

    wcout << targetHwnd << endl;
    DWORD targetPID;
    DWORD targetTID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(targetHwnd, &targetPID);

    dllInstance = LoadLibrary(L"DLL1.dll");
    setHook = (DLLFUNC_SETHOOK)GetProcAddress(dllInstance, "setHook");
    if (dllInstance == NULL) {
        cout << "ERROR: dllInstance is NULL\n";
        return 1;
    }
    if (setHook == NULL) {
        cout << "ERROR: setHook function is NULL\n";
        return 1;
    }

    hook = setHook(targetTID);
    if (hook == NULL) {
        cout << "ERROR: Could not set hook\n";
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "INFO: Hooked successfully\n";

    //Works only when targetHwnd is a children
    SendMessage(targetHwnd, WM_USER + 1, 0, 0); //This causes the crash

    cin.ignore();

    BOOL success = UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
    if (success == FALSE) {
        cout << "ERROR: Could not unhook\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "INFO: Unhooked hook. Exiting...\n";
    }
}
```

The DLL(DLL1):

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>

extern HINSTANCE hInst;
extern std::wofstream logfile;
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) HHOOK __stdcall setHook(DWORD targetTid);

HINSTANCE hInst;
std::wofstream logfile;

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    hInst = hModule;
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH: { 
            logfile.open("D:\\projects\\crashDemo\\log.txt"); //run "Get-Content -Path "log.txt" -Wait" in Powershell for realtime logs
            break;
        }
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH: break;
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH: break;
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH: {
            logfile.close();
            break;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK wmProcCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (nCode >= HC_ACTION) {
        PCWPSTRUCT cwpStruct = (PCWPSTRUCT)lParam;
        switch (cwpStruct->message) {
        case WM_USER + 1:
            logfile << "WM_USER+1 Message received" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) HHOOK __stdcall setHook(DWORD targetTid) {
    return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, wmProcCallback, hInst, targetTid);
}
```

EDIT: I did debug through. It looks like everything is ok with the dll. It loads and the `wmProcCallback` is called several times as it should.
Also my `WM_USER+1` is recognized but after handling all messages in the `wmProcCallback` it closes the window immediately and leaves the following error message.

[image]

So I got 4 error messages in total:

1. & 2. `An outgoing call cannot be made since the application is dispatching an input-asynchronous call`
2. `The operation is not permitted because the calling application is not the owner of the data on the clipboard.`
3. `Unspecified error`

Does someone know which of them relevant because I don't know any of these errors? Gonna do some research now. Would be nice if someone can help out on this.

Comment: all your details is unrelated. if crash - error in your code. but your code you not show

Comment: ok gonna provide some code.

Comment: @Nur1 You are hooking a *thread*, so `wmProcCallback()` is going to receive ALL dispatched messages for ALL windows belonging to that thread.  Your crash is going to end up being due to a logic error inside of `wmProcCallback()`, but wee can't see that code, so we can't diagnose the error.

Comment: and you must at first debug ! look where crash/exception - no simply say crash. place, callstack, symbols must be

Comment: I updated my question with some demo code. Thanks so far.

Comment: No. You updated the question with links to off-site resources. That's not helpful. Please read [ask].

Comment: `switch (ul_reason_for_call)` have no `break;` as result you call `logfile.close();` just after `logfile.open` and multiple times, after every thread create/exit/dll unload

Comment: @RbMm It was missing in the demo I prepared, sry about that, added it!

Comment: [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices). Don't forget, you're a guest in someone else's house, so you better play by the rules.

Comment: attach debugger to process, if was unhandled exception - look - where it, call stack, etc

Comment: probably crash in `logfile << *`

Comment: @RbMm gonna look forward to debug this properly. The crash still occurs even without any logging.

Comment: @IInspectable I read this page and always look back to it. If we took out the logging this will be a tiny dll which should (and do) work. But as in my question, it's all about the hwnd somehow... :(

Comment: If you want to identify the issue, remove the code that is known to be incorrect. Please update the question.

Comment: @IInspectable There is no code that is known to be incorrect. I just said that it still behaves the same even if the logging is not there at all. The last update contains a full example and I adapted the entire question for it.

Comment: The logging **is** there. If you want help with your code, show the code you are using.

Comment: @IInspectable I am using it with logging :) "If you want help with your code, show the code you are using." I literally created a full example here

Comment: Executing C++ code from `DllMain` is guaranteed to be broken. Just remove it. Using global objects in a DLL is broken. Remove it. If you want to solve this all by yourself, be my guest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233956/discussion-between-nur1-and-iinspectable).

Comment: What you really need to do is debug the crash in explorer. All we can do without that is guess. (For example, your code takes action when `nCode > HC_ACTION` even though it should take action only when `nCode == HC_ACTION`. Is that the problem? We need the explorer crash stack to know for sure.)

Comment: @RaymondChen At this point, I am not sure if this is a crash. The window just closes. And if several explorer windows are open only the hooked one is closed. I did debug through, the dll seems ok and the wmProcCallback function is also executed when receiving messages. but the closure happens after.

Comment: Are you trying to inject a 32-bit hook into a 64-bit process? [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) calls out that in that case, the thread which sets the hook must pump messages, but yours doesn't.

Comment: @RaymondChen Both explorer.exe and my demo code runs on x64. I am aware of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix, don't use WM_USER+1 :)